# Cookie path and its accessibility to subfolder pages

Tags: url, cookies, httpcookie, global-path, url-path

Let's say I have a website with domain: `www.example.com`

If I set a cookie with path `'***/***'` the cookie will be accessible via all pages in the domain, eg:

- `www.example.com/page1.html`
- `www.example.com/subfolder1/page1.html`
- `www.example.com/subfolder1/moresubfolder1/page1.html`, etc.

What if we set the cookie to path `'/subfolder1'`, will the cookie will be made available to any page or subfolder beneath the folder? Eg:

- `www.example.com/subfolder1/moresubfolder/page1.html`

So, if not, I guess, I have no choice but to use path `'/'` for those cookies, right?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> If we set the cookie to path **'/subfolder1'**, will the cookie will be made available to any page or subfolder beneath the folder?

Yes. The cookie *will* be available to all pages and subdirectories *within* the `/subfolder1` path.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014024/set-cookie-wildcard-path for the relevant specification.  For those who didn't know, cookies are only accessible to the specified path and any subpaths, no superpaths.  So cookies for the path "/folder/subfolder1/" are not accessible to "/folder/".  I banged my head on this one for a bit.

Comment: @SampleJACK ouch, that explains MY problem quite nicely!

Comment: @Alex, so how do we get a cookie that is for `/subfolder1` but **not** `/subfolder1/inner-folder`?

Comment: @Pacerier the answer we are commenting on is correct, were you asking something else?

Comment: @SampleJACK how do we get a cookie that is for /subfolder1 but not /subfolder1/inner-folder?

Comment: As I understand it, that's not possible. Cookies apply to all lower paths (unless you set a different cookie for the lower down path, ie in our case on  /subfolder1/inner-folder)

Answer (score 17):

To remove some ambiguity by reusing a portion of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314164/575766) answer:

> A request-path path-matches a given cookie-path if at least one of the
>   following conditions holds:
>
> - The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.
> - The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the last    character of the cookie-path is %x2F ("/").
> - The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the first    character of the request-path that is not included in the cookie-
>     path is a %x2F ("/") character.

There is a slight (but potentially important) difference between setting a cookie on the `/subfolder1` path and the `/subfolder1/` path.

If you rely on the former your request path needs to start with a "%x2F ("/") character" (a forward slash) to guarantee the desired behaviour. For an example, take a look at the linked answer.

Setting the cookie path to simply `/` avoids any edge cases, but as you say - the cookie would be accessible the entire domain.

Comment: most informing answer

Comment: what is the difference between `/subfolder1` and `/subfolder1/`? From the linked answer, the only difference is : the request path `/subfolder1KKK` also match cookie path `/subfolder1`, right? And different browser may has different behavior, e.g. IE match request path `/subfolder1KKK` to cookie path `/subfolder1`, but firefox will not, right?

Comment: *No difference* between `/subfolder1` and `/subfolder1/` according to the quoted RFC.  The only way it makes a difference is if a browser doesn't implement this rule (i.e. `IE`). Only cookie-path `/subfolder1/` can match point 2; request-path `/subfolder1ABC` will not match cookie-path `/subfolder1`, since the first non-matching character is `A`, not `/`, so it does not satisfy point 3.

Answer (score 13):

if we set the cookie to path `/subfolder1`, the following pages in the example are accessible:

> www.example.com/subfolder1/page1.html
>   www.example.com/subfolder1/moresubfolder1/page1.html
>   etc.

However, the page `www.example.com/page1.html` will not be accessible as it does not belong to the allowed path.

Answer (score 2):

For example, there are 7 urls below which can access the cookie with the global path `/`:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/a/
https://example.com/a/a-1/
https://example.com/a/a-2/
https://example.com/b/
https://example.com/b/b-1/
https://example.com/b/b-2/
```

Then, the cookie with the path `/b` can be accessed by 3 urls below:

```
https://example.com/b/
https://example.com/b/b-1/
https://example.com/b/b-2/
```