# Using the same cookie in two logins

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I need your help

I've a MVC project that uses Jquery, where I've implemented a mechanism of "Remember Me" using cookies to save, clear and retrieve the login and password.

I also have two screens where the user does the login. I want that both logins manipulate the same cookie. I've got to implement it, but I've realized that each one has a different behaviour. I mean, the cookie's value I save in the first login is not the same than the value that retrieves the second login (when I open it). In other words, if I mark "remind me" on the first login, it isn't reflected on the second login and viceversa. What can I do to make that both of them manipulate and read the same values from the same cookie? Is it possible?

PS: For this situations I'm using the same web navigator: Firefox or IE.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are specific to the domain that creates them. If you are having two login screens,you need to have them under the same domain ( some thing like login.yourdomain.com if you have more than one domain)

Sri

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know that, but in this situation both logins are under the same domain. The same behaviour happens when I open the same login screen in different navigators. Seems like the cookie was handled independently.

Comment: Cookie is specific to Domain and Browser. You can never access a cookie set in IE from Firefox.

Comment: Fine, I understand the part of the browsers. About the domain, this means that if I have only one cookie for two login URLs like these "http://companyname/login" and a "http://companyname/main/login" they won't be able to access to the same cookie?

Comment: Try setting the Cookie path and see if that solves the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages

Answer (score 0):

you can change the cookie domain, if you are using formsauthentication.
if not, you should also be able to change it.

just take the same domain name for both sites.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiedomain.aspx

hth