# Set-Cookie: Wildcard "Path"

Tags: http, cookies

Is it possible to place a wildcard infront of the "path" parameter in a HTTP Set-Cookie request?

example:

```
Set-Cookie: SSID=foo; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/*/Stuff; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Comment: i wish this could be possible

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Check [RFC 6265 HTTP State Management Mechanism, 5.1.4.  Paths and Path-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4):

```
 A request-path path-matches a given cookie-path if at least one of
   the following conditions holds:

   o  The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.

   o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the last
      character of the cookie-path is %x2F ("/").

   o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the first
      character of the request-path that is not included in the cookie-
      path is a %x2F ("/") character.
```

It does not mention any wildcard handling, so it's not possible to use wildcards in the path.