# No cookie set in subfolder

Tags: javascript, cookies, permissions, subdirectory

I got a function which sets a cookie that remembers the clicked image. If the file is in the root folder, everything works just fine. If I put the same file in a subfolder, the cookie will just not being set.

Here's my code.

```
function FensterOeffnen (Variable) {
    var a = new Date();
    a = new Date(a.getTime() +1000*5);
    document.cookie = 'uebergabe='+Variable+'; expires='+ 
                      a.toGMTString()+';';
    window.location.href="../test2.html";   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how `document.cookie` works by default. Since you do not specify a path for the cookie, the default is the subfolder where your script resides. Reference:

> Any of the following cookie attribute values can optionally follow the
>   key-value pair, specifying the cookie to set/update, and preceded by a
>   semi-colon separator:
>
> - `;path=path` (e.g., '/', '/mydir') If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location.

So the cookie you are setting has a path of e.g. `/mydir`. This means that it's not valid for scripts outside that path [according to RFC 6265](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016137/50079).

If you want the cookie to be accessible throughout your site, you have to add `;path=/` manually:

```
document.cookie = 'uebergabe='+Variable+'; expires='+ 
                  a.toGMTString()+';path=/';
```

Comment: Ran across this issue today and this solution worked for me as well! :)