# How could I handle authentication separately for multidomain sites?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I need some clarifications about multi-domain authentication. I have a site, e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), which uses sys_folder id = 25 which has own users and groups. And now I created another domain using site configuration, [www.example.com/mycompany](http://www.example.com/mycompany), which uses another sys_folder id = 50. Both have felogin with different storage folders. It is correctly working in login failures. But when I logged in my main website, say  [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). It automatically logged-in on other domain [www.example.com/mycompany](http://www.example.com/mycompany), which shows my fe_users details. How could I handle authentication separately for domain-wise? Does TYPO3 support that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general issue and not really related to TYPO3: when you log in to `www.example.com`, the cookie path will be `/`. It cannot be anything else since it would then be limited to that path.

Thus when you enter a sub-site like `www.example.com/mycompany`, the cookie of `www.example.com` is sent since `/mycompany` is covered by the `/` path. See [Set-Cookie: Wildcard "Path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014024) for details.

The proper solution here can only be to separate sites using subdomains instead, e.g. `mycompany.example.com` and `www.example.com`. Then each site will have its domain stored in the cookie which ensures only the correct cookie per site is used.

Notice that in this case the main site **must** be something like `www.example.com` and not just `example.com`, otherwise the same issue will show up: a login cookie created on `example.com` will be sent for `mycompany.example.com` and all other subdomains.

Comment: Yes, it is not the TYPO3 issue . It now logs in separately without problem. Thanks for the effort.