# Angular SPA which is used as Frontend for my custom OIDC provider is not sending session cookie to my backend /signin API

Tags: angular, cookies, openid-connect, samesite, node-oidc-provider

Senario

I have a two angular Apps first one is a `angular_shop` an which use `/auth` endpoint for a custom  node_oidc_provider to start auth request

node_oidc_provider the checks the PKCE code from `angular_shop` and redirects to  second angular  app `angular_oidc_frontend` which acts as a frontend of custom identity provider created using [node_oidc_provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-provider)

I can see that the redirection to `http:localhost:4200/signin?uid=WIkb3oodGHMOTgg4mlkyQ` is happening successfully

But now i have two problems

1. the session cookie set by `node_oidc_provider` is not visible in application tab of the chrome in first load of angular application, but it can be seen if i refresh the angular application page.

[image]
[image]

2. Second problem is that even though the cookie `sameSite` is set to `None` the two cookie visible is not send to the server when i submit the login details to `localhost:8081/api/v1/sigin` endpoind to the idp sever which is created using `node_oidc_provider`

Here is the request and response header to `/signin` endpoint which i logged at server

```
    Received headers: {
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/signin?uid=PbR6zZdrqGsDauDy-Sb1X',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
  'content-length': '116',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:8081'
}
Sent headers: [Object: null prototype] {
  'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,skip',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
}
```

**Note**: initially i though this must be due to two different origin 'http://localhost:4200`and`http://localhost:8081` so setup a proxy at angular cli  with following setup

```
{
    "/temp": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8081",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/temp": ""
      },
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin":true,
      "cookieDomainRewrite":"localhost"
    }
  }
```

Also the angular app is also configured to send the  `withCredentials: true`  for `/signin` endpoint.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: true 
};
```

Other configuration at the backend is as following

**oidc-provide cookie-config:**

```
cookies: {
    keys: ['ewdewdewdewdewdwd', 'dewdewdwedwedwedewd', 'dwedwedwdwd'],
    long: {
        signed: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 86400 * 1000, // 1 day in milliseconds
        // Add secure flag in production
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        // Add sameSite policy (strict, lax, or none)
        sameSite: 'none',
    },
    short: {
        signed: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        // Add secure flag in production
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        // Add sameSite policy (strict, lax, or none)
        sameSite: 'none',
    },
    names: {
        session: '_session',
        interaction: '_interaction',
        resume: '_resume',
        state: '_state',
    },
   
},
```

**custom interaction policy created**

```
const interactions = policy();
interactions.add(new Prompt({
    name: 'signin',
    requestable: true,
    check: async (ctx) => {
        // Here, you check if the user is already authenticated
        // If not, you'll prompt for login
        return !ctx.oidc.session || !ctx.oidc.session.accountId;
    },
}), 0);
```

**created policy modified to redirect to correct url**

```
 interactions: {
        policy: interactions,
        url(ctx, interaction) {console.info('interaction',interaction)
            return `${process.env.IDENTITY_FRONTEND_URL}/signin?uid=${interaction.uid}`;
        },
    },
```

**And here is my CROS config at the server**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

    // Request method you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,skip');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the request sent 
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    // Pass to the next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

**And my `/signin` endpoint**

```
signIn: async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');
        }

        const interactionId = req.body.uid || req.query.uid || req.params.uid ;

        if (!interactionId) {
            return res.status(400).send('Interaction token is missing');
        }
        //console.info('req incoming',req);
        const details = await oidcProvider.interactionDetails(req, res);
        console.log(details);
        assert.equal(details.interaction.uid, interactionId);

        const { prompt: { name }, params, session } = details;

        if (name === 'signin') {
            // Assuming you have a method or a way to get accountId from req.user
            const accountId = req.user._id.toString(); // Use a unique identifier for the user
            
            const result = {
                login: { accountId },
            };

            await oidcProvider.interactionFinished(req, res, result, { mergeWithLastSubmission: false });
        } else {
            res.status(400).send('Unsupported interaction type');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred during authentication');
    }
},
```

**And for visibility here the error at server due to no `cookie` being detected**

```
{
  allow_redirect: true,
  error: 'invalid_request',
  status: 400,
  statusCode: 400,
  expose: true,
  error_description: 'interaction session id cookie not found',
  error_detail: undefined
}
```

Also in production i plan to use `nginx` to reverse proxy  angular_oidc_frontend app and ipd nodejs api  to serve from same domain to resolve the `sameSite` cookie problem.

Advanced sorry for the long post, its a bit tricky to make short explanation for this complex flow between the apps, what i am implementing is ( Authorisation code flow ) oidc  in custom idp (identity service provider) server created using `node_oidc_provider`

Comment: I have been banging my head against the wall for last 24 hours , any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand but did you check the cookie path ? According to the 2dn "dev tools" screenshot, the cookie path is `/signin`, meaning that it will only be sent with requests starting with `localhost:4200/signin` and it seems to me that you are using `localhost:4200/api/v1/signin` instead. Can you try to change the cookie path and see if it is sent ?

Comment: wow,  thanks man it worked . it was the problem

now setting path to `/` . previously  i was expecting to restrict the cookie to be set on only `/signin`   but that was causing  this  problem .

Apparently : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014024/set-cookie-wildcard-path.

if you have time post  it as answer, i will mark it as answer . thanks for the help
@ArnaudDenoyelle

Comment: your suggestion solved my 2nd problem now i will look into angular's first time load issue and update here if i found the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the 2dn "dev tools" screenshot, the cookie path is `/signin`, meaning that it will only be sent with requests starting with `localhost:4200/signin`

[image: Cookie path]

But login details are sent to `localhost:4200/api/v1/signin` instead so the cookie will be ignored

Changing the cookie path to `/` should solve the problem.