# Internet Explorer sends the wrong cookie when the paths overlap

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

We have multiple copies of a web-app that is deployed on multiple paths on the same domain.
Example:

- http://mydomain.com/abc
- http://mydomain.com/xyz
- http://mydomain.com/abc123

Each instance maintains a set of cookies each one defines its `path` as `"/" + .getWebDirRoot()` - i.e. `/abc`, `/xyz`, `/abc123`

When performing the following flow:

- Login to http://mydomain.com/abc
- Perform some activity
- Logout
- Login to http://mydomain.com/abc123
- Perform some activity **<-- Failure**

The last step fails since `IE` sent us the incorrect cookie - it sends the one for http://mydomain.com/abc instead of the one for http://mydomain.com/abc123

This does not happen in FireFox. (And I haven't tried any other browser).

Is this a known behavior of `IE` (I tested `IE9` and `IE8`)?
Is there a way to overcome it (in a programmatic manner)?

**Note:** Just to clarify, this does not happen when switching from http://mydomain.com/abc to http://mydomain.com/xyz - the behavior is strictly restricted to flows where `currentUrl.startswith(urlAssociatedWithCookie) == true`

I checked the behavior using **Fiddler** - I clearly see the HTTP request for `abc123` sent with the value of the cookie belonging to `abc`.

I also checked the cookies on FireFox and they are as expected - one created per path.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After investigating for more than a day and looking everywhere for specification on IE's behaviour I came up with nothing - apart from the understanding that when `IE` sees a cookie from domain `xyz` and path `abc`, it will send it on any request sent to any URL starting with the same domain and path, e.g. `http://xyz/abc123'.

So eventually what I did was change my cookie creation, and instead of:

```
Name: mycookie
Path: /abc
```

I now create the following:

```
Name: mycookie
Path: /abc/
```

This solved the problem with no ricochetes - the cookie is saved succesfuly on the client and the correct cookie is always sent to the server.

---

**Note:** I checked the [RFC for HTTP Cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) and found this:

> A request-path path-matches a given cookie-path if at least one of
> the following conditions holds:
>
> o  The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.
>
> o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the last
> character of the cookie-path is %x2F ("/").
>
> o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the first
> character of the request-path that is not included in the cookie-
> path is a %x2F ("/") character.

The scenario that should have applied here is the 3rd, but it looks like `IE` does not comply with the RFC on this case ...

Comment: Thanks for a thorough investigation. Knowing this will probably save me much drama in the future.

Comment: It happened the same to me (and taken the same conclusion). Thanks for saving me the time to find the spec and the description of the bug in IE!

Comment: For everybody deploying on Apache Tomcat: Starting with Tomcat7 Tomcat automatically adds a trailing slash ("/") to the cookie path to avoid this problem. You can disable this feature in your `context.xml` by setting `sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash=false` (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: This appears to be fixed in IE11, if you happen to still care!

Comment: @sparrowt - not even remotely :)