# CakePHP needs to set session for particular folders

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am using **CakePHP framework**. And below is my problem.
**www.mysite.com** is the main site and I've created 5-6 different demos of my original site with different colors and fonts.

So, if I am login in **www.mysite.com/demo1** and then I open another demo **www.mysite.com/demo2**, it shows I'm logged in already.

Is there any way to set session folder wise?

Comment: these all 5-6 demos are separate cakePHP folders?

Comment: yes. all have their own cakephp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages

Comment: Set session variable, that specifies folder. If folder does not match, logout user

Comment: ok..thanks...let me try and will get back to this conversation

Comment: I have tried this in cakephp core file but no luck
 'session.cookie_path' => '/app/dir/demo1'

Answer (score 1):

In core.php, few lines before EOF, says:

```
//Prefix each application on the same server with a different string, to avoid Memcache and APC conflicts.
$prefix = 'myapp_';
```

Have you tried different prefix for each site?

Comment: I will try this one but using cookie path, my problem has been solved.