# Persisting jQuery Cookies Across Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using the jQuery Cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and I'm having issues persisting my cookies across different pages on my website.

I have a piece of content that displays on each page and once hidden it sets the cookie like so (Apologies for all of the variables, they are not at all relevent :

```
// Binds the close event to the button.
$alert.on('click', function(e) {
    $alertWrap.fadeOut();

    // Sets the breaking-delete cookie to yes.
    $.cookie('breaking-bar-delete', 'yes', {expires: 7 });
});
```

When the initial script fires it checks to see if the cookie exists:

```
// If the current bar is not supressed and they are not in the editor, and they do not have a closed cookie it will setup the bar.
if ($.cookie('breaking-bar-delete') == undefined) {
  $alert.css("display","block");
}

// If there's no news, or they have the closed cookie for the current bar it hides it by default.
if ($.cookie('breaking-bar-delete') == 'yes') {
  $alert.parent().css("display","none");
}
```

Now this works for the path that you hide the bar on so it doesn't re-display if you refresh. But if you go to a part of the site with a different path it doesn't detect the cookie and displays the content.

Is there some sort of configuration I can set when I initially serve the cookie so it persists throughout all of the pages on my site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookie path and its accessibility to subfolder pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Path**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#path):-

> **path**
>
> path: '/' Define the path where the cookie is valid.
>
> By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was
> created (standard browser behavior).
>
> If you want to make it available
> for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'.
>
> Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

So, for your cookie:-

```
$.cookie('breaking-bar-delete', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Youch, didn't see that one. Thanks!