# Cookie not available in different directory

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookie-path

According to MDN, cookies set with a path of '/' [are available anywhere in the same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies). This is corroborated by [several](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576535/7669110) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_path).

However, I just haven't found this to be the case. I ran the following test on (nonexistent) directories on `google.com` using firefox:

```
> window.location = 'https://google.com/dir/file.html'
Navigated to https://google.com/dir/file.html
"https://google.com/dir/file.html"
> document.cookie
""
> document.cookie = 'key1=value1,path=/'
"key1=value1,path=/"
> document.cookie
"key1=value1,path=/"
> window.location = '/dir2/file.html'
Navigated to https://google.com/dir2/file.html
"/dir2/file.html"
> document.cookie
""
```

Am I misunderstanding something? What am I doing wrong? I tried similar tests on Chrome with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was setting `path` with a comma delimiter, not a semicolon delimiter. It was writing the cookie literally as I typed it, instead of interpreting the path and domain.

The correct way to write the cookie would have been `document.cookie = 'key1=value1;path=/'`.